# Raw Disk VirtualBox Windows 10 Guest in Pop!_OS no bootable medium

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, boot, virtualbox

I have a laptop with Pop!_OS installed and I don't want to partition or touch that hard drive at all since it is my main work machine.  I installed a second hard drive and put Windows 10 on it, so the machine is now dual-booting on two separate hard drives.

Next, I'd love to virtualize the Windows 10 installation inside Pop!_OS.  I created a vmdk that points to the SSD I installed Windows 10 on and created a machine but I get a "No bootable medium found!".  I also used `VBoxManage storageattach "Windows 10" --storagectl "SATA" --port 0 --device 0 --type hdd --medium ~/VirtualBox\ VMs/win10.vmdk` to attach the drive, but it still gives me the same error.

I'm not sure if it means anything or not but gparted shows two partitions that seem suspect labeled "boot/efi" and "msftdata" on my main Linux partition:

[GParted partition table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2YYsD.png)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right, you have installed Windows in a situation of dual boot
on your main disk and would now like to move Windows into a vmdk.
This was not the right way to achieve that.

My guess is that your boot device is the first disk, so the Windows disk has no boot
capabilities by itself - you boot it through the first disk.

I suggest to set on the VM a Windows ISO as boot device, and re-install Windows
while running from the virtual product (VMware?).
You could probably get by doing only a
[Startup Repair](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/27649-run-startup-repair-windows-10-a.html)
rather than a full installation of Windows 10.

I suggest before starting to undo the dual boot, since after the above is finished
I'm not sure that the dual boot will still work.